Fantasy manhwa where the female lead is a demon that was summoned by a human for revenge
The female lead has blonde hair and red eyes. She's a demon who was summoned by a pregnant and injured woman who was being chased by the father of the child. As the woman was dying she summoned a demon to avenge their death, and the demon took over the baby's body.
